# How can I get the value of 2 columns, not only one?

Tags: c#, mysql

I want the result of two columns and not only one. I tried:

```
MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("traceid", "idref"));
```

But it does not work. I am a beginner with C#, can anyone please help?

```
String str = @"server=localhost;database=asianimport;userid=tera;password=******;";
MySqlConnection con = null;

try
{
    con = new MySqlConnection(str);
    con.Open(); //open the connection
    MessageBox.Show("connect " );

    String cmdText = "SELECT * FROM tracerecord limit 3";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdText, con);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("traceid", "idref"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `GetString()` twice, one per field:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    String traceID = reader.GetString("traceid");
    String idRef = reader.GetString("idref");
    MessageBox.Show(traceID + " - " + idRef);
}
```

Comment: Thank you 
Michiel van Vaardegem

Answer (score 2):

reader.GetString() returns the result from only one column of your current record. Use them separatly for each colunm with concatanation:

```
MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("traceid")+ " "+reader.GetString("idref"));
```